# searching form in php with drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery

Good day! I'm just a newbie in php programming so I need somebody to help me with this one. I still cannot find what's wrong with this code. I created a search form with drop down menu to filter the results. But nothing happens when I do a searching. It's either it's just refreshes the page or display error criteria message. any answer will be appreciated! :) thanks in advance! Here is the code:

```
   <html>
    <head>
<basefont face="Arial">
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
// form not submitted
?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
search  
  <input type="text" name="search">
   <select size="1" name="dropdown">
    <option value="" selected>search By...</option>
    <option value="first">Company</option>
    <option value="last">Address</option>  
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
}

else {

// Server Variables
$host = "localhost";
$user = "mdti";
$pass = "tnet";
$db = "ojt";

$search = empty($_POST['search'])? die ("ERROR: Enter search Criteria") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);


// Open Connection

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect to host");

//Select Database

mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to connect to database");

//Create query

$query = "SELECT arCompanyname, arAddress FROM ar WHERE $dropdown like'$search'" or die (mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close($connect);

echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$company=mysql_result($result,$i,"arCompanyname");
$address=mysql_result($result,$i,"arAddress");


echo "<br>Company: $company<br><br>Address: $address<hr><br>";

$i++;

}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also please change `like'$search'` with `like '%$search%'`

Comment: it displayed "Unknown column 'first' in 'where clause' error. I did '%$seach%' but it outputs the same error message @zzlalani

Comment: Please check my answer and the query I suggest, i'm not completely sure if you are looking for this particularly, but this might help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, initial thought is:

```
change like'$search' with like '%$search%'

change mysql_numrows to mysql_num_rows

check the dropdwon option values 'arCompanyname' and 'arAddress' matching your field names.

change <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> to <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Comment: i still got an error message saying that No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/MDTIFINAL/webpages/<?=$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]?>\ –

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mysql_real_escape_string` without opening the `mysql_connect`.. you need to call the connect code above the `mysql_real_escape_string` code

```
// Open Connection

$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect to host");

$search = empty($_POST['search'])? die ("ERROR: Enter search Criteria") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);
```

Also you need to change the select option values

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
search  
  <input type="text" name="search">
   <select size="1" name="dropdown">
    <option value="" selected>search By...</option>
    <option value="arCompanyname">Company</option>
    <option value="arAddress">Address</option>  
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"> 
</form>
```

and change your query with

```
SELECT arCompanyname, arAddress FROM ar WHERE $dropdown LIKE '%$search%'
```

Comment: i still got an error message saying that No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/MDTIFINAL/webpages/<?=$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]?>\

Comment: try changing `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` to `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

Comment: or else keep the form's action attribute empty like `action=""` this will also post the form to the same page..

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated code:

Updated the search query, mysql_numrows -> [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), added [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for looping.

Try to write your scripts using [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions. Because mysql_ * functions going to deprecated.

```
<html>
    <head>
<basefont face="Arial">
</head>
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
// form not submitted
?>

<form action="" method="post">
search  
  <input type="text" name="search">
   <select size="1" name="dropdown">
    <option value="" selected>search By...</option>
    <option value="first">Company</option>
    <option value="last">Address</option>  
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
}

else {

    // Server Variables
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "mdti";
    $pass = "tnet";
    $db = "ojt";

    // Open Connection
    
    $connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect to host");

    $search = empty($_POST['search'])? die ("ERROR: Enter search Criteria") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);


    //Select Database

    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to connect to database");

    //Create query

    $query = "SELECT arCompanyname, arAddress FROM ar WHERE $dropdown like '%$search%'";


    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num > 0) {


        echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $company = $row['arCompanyname'];
            $address = $row['arAddress'];


            echo "<br>Company: $company<br><br>Address: $address<hr><br>";


        }

    
    } else {

        echo "No rows found";
    }
    
    mysql_close($connect);  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use " mysql_real_escape_string"

```
$search = empty($_POST['search'])? die ("ERROR: Enter search Criteria") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$dropdown = empty($_POST['dropdown'])? die ("ERROR: Select from dropdown") : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dropdown']);
```

And change '$search' to '%$search%'

```
$query = "SELECT arCompanyname, arAddress FROM ar WHERE $dropdown like'%$search%'" or die (mysql_error());
```

change mysql_numrows to mysql_num_rows